# grails command line application

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a grails web application with a domain model and a hibernate datasource persistence.

I would like to write now a command line tool in groovy to access also this domain model and the hibernate datasource.

Any ideas how I can do this?

regards
Vanigor

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring Boot as described in [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm/) article.

That example creates a small web UI, but Boot can be configured as a CLI app.